# How can I get a value according to a number I give on C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question for you all. For example, I have a table on a certain SQL database like this:

```
ID = 1
First Name = Kutay
Last Name = Ertürk
Balance = 1275
Password = 0129
RFID = 8310612212
```

If I give the rfid number, I want to get the other values like first and last names. I have tried everything I could but it's no use.

Here's the code I want to fix:

```
public string GetByName(string key)
{
    using (ATMServerContext atmServerContext = new ATMServerContext())
    {
        ATM atm = (from x in atmServerContext.Atms
                   where x.RFID == key
                   select x).SingleOrDefault();
                   
        if (atm != null)
        {
            return atm.FirstName + " " + atm.LastName;
        }
        else
        {
            return "couldnotfound";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the atm value returns null and I get "couldnotfound". I definitely have a problem with the atm value.

Here's what's inside the context:

```
public class ATMServerContext:DbContext
{
    public ATMServerContext()
    {
        
    }
    public DbSet<ATM> Atms { get; set; }
}
```

I hope you could fix my problem. I know it is a basic problem but if I could do this, I will be very happy.

Comment: Are there records in `atmServerContext.Atms`? What is the value of `key` *exactly*?

Comment: We need more details to be able to help. *Most likely* you have the wrong connection string and are pointing to a database other than the one you want

Comment: key's value is the same as the rfid number. I am sure about it.

Comment: connection string is ok. I tried to add a member to it as a test and it worked.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column RFID in your table?

Comment: the datatype is string.

Comment: That code should work unless you are using a different database or the parameter passed to the funcion (key) is not correct. Did you check for spaces or other hidden characters? What happen if you add  _key = key.Trim()_ before running the query?

Comment: Consider using `x.FRID.Equals(key)` for string comparison

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: **x.RFID == key**

If **RFID** and **key** definitely match that code should work just fine; either key isn't what you expect, or RFID isn't what you expect, or the comparison regarding the datatypes isn't what you expect.

When a LINQ statement looks completely correct but still doesn't give the right result (or is very slow) the best thing to do is load up **SQL Server Profiler** (assuming you're doing LINQ over SQL Server), and put a trace on your client's hostname / username / application name (EntityFramework by default).

You will then see exactly the SQL that is being generated, and can run it in SQL Server Management studio. I'm sure as soon as you see the SQL being generated you'll quickly see why that where clause isn't behaving as expected.

**Definitely invest in learning to use the Profiler**; there is a bit of a learning curve but it will save you lots of time. (It is also great for seeing what 3rd party applications are doing on the database.)